# Scala, List to Pairs (elem, lastElement)

Tags: scala

I have a list
`List(1,2,3,99)` and I want to get a `List((1,99),(2,99),(3,99))`. I'm trying to use the `zip` function but I guess that there's a direct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me most readable seems using `zip`, zipping with the last element repeated infinitely:

```
l.init zip Stream.continually(l.last)
```

The drawback is `l.last` is evaluated repeatedly, therefore if you care for performance with large lists, you might prefer assigning that to a value first:

```
val last = l.last
l.init zip Stream.continually(last)
```

or you can use `from` with a zero step to avoid lazy evaluation:

```
l.init zip Stream.from(l.last, 0)
```

A similar version can be done using `map`, mapping all but last elements tupled with the last one - again, `l.last` will be evaluated on each iteration unless substituted by a variable:

```
l.init map ((_, l.last))
```

If you change you input so that the repeated element comes first (`List(99,1,2,3)`), you can use `l.head` and `l.tail` instead of `l.last` and `l.init`, which is more natural and has no performance drawbacks:

```
l.tail zip Stream.continually(l.head)
```

or:

```
l.tail map ((_, l.head))
```

Comment: With the Stream class seems easier. I didn't know that class.

Comment: Note that `List#last` is a partial function: `scala> List().last
java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the best solution but here it goes:

```
l map ((_, l.last)) init
```

Another crazy idea might be:

```
l.init zip List.fill(l.length -1)(l.last)
```

Comment: `Selects all elements except the last`
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@init:Repr

Answer (score 1):

with this code you don't need to fear lists with one element or that are empty.

```
val resultList:List[(Int,Int)] = List(1,2,3,99) match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: Nil => //do what you have to do if there is only one element
  case xs => xs.init zip Stream.continually(xs.last) //an infinit stream of the last element
}
```

Comment: Second case is not necessary: third will return empty list, as `xs.init` will be empty for a one-element list.

Comment: That is right, but maybe he have a requirement how to handle this case. Case 2 is there for logical not technical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension, for a given list `xs`,

```
for (i <- xs.init; z = xs.last) yield (i,z)
```

In an ordered collection, `init` delivers all but the last elements.

**Update**

An approach that handles empty lists as well,

```
for (i <- xs.dropRight(1); z <- xs.takeRight(1)) yield (i,z)
```

Comment: I like this very much. Using `for` is a nice way how to introduce a variable for `last` without having to use multiple statements.